# Is it possible to fix the positions of last three slides within the slick slider?

Tags: javascript, shopify, css-position, slick.js, product-variations

The scenario is as follows:-
I am working on an E-commerce site. There on product page I have products with variants. I want to show thumbnails that belongs to a particular variant.
For example, if I have clicked RED variant I want only red coloured shirts to appear under main-image as thumbnails.
[image: this image gives an example of what I have right now]
In addition to the selected variant image I also want 2 more slides to appear that would be common to each variant.
I hope I have been specific to my question. Please give me a solution. (I am using slick slider using CDN)

I am new to java script. I don't know how to get the values of fixed slides

Comment: use alt to identify the images related to variant and hide/show them on frontend when variant is changed

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your products by parameter:

```
const products = [
    {name: 'shirt1', color: 'red'},
    {name: 'shirt2', color: 'blue'},
    {name: 'shirt3', color: 'white'},
    {name: 'shirt4', color: 'red'}
]

function filterByColor(color){
    let filteredProducts = products.filter(product => product.color == color)
}
```

So your Button must have function onClick:

```
<button onClick=filterByColor('red')>Only Red Shirts</button>
```